# Particle collision

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics

At the end of Chapter 3 in Griffiths "Introduction to elementary particles", he mentions that one can benefit from a change in frames, in this case, center-of-mass (CM) frame and particle-rest frame. From two identical particle collisions, he obtains kinetic energy in particle rest frame (T') in terms of the kinetic energy on CM frame (T). He includes a comment about how the relativistic formula has an important extra term compared to the classical one.

He mentions:

> "The classical answer would have been T' = 4T. (...) Now, a factor of 4
>   is some benefit, to be sure, but the relativistic gain can be greater
>   by far. Colliding electrons with a laboratory kinetic energy of l GeV,
>   for example. would have relativistic energy of 4000 GeV."

I don't understand this "Benefit" in energy. Why would I have a benefit just changing frames? In my lab I'm only "watching" things happening in the CM frame. I can't benefit from what happens in other frames if I can't "reach" them.

Comment: If you are striving to explore phenomena at the highest effective energy achievable, and you have trouble  pumping extremely high energies into a particle, frames such as the c.m. frame give you maximum bang for your buck. Isn't that a benefit?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Ok, so he is just referring to how hard it would be to achieve high energies in the other frame. (If one particle is at rest.)

Comment: It's basically the difference between fixed-target and symmetric beam collisions

Comment: In the  more than  50 years of working with  experiments in particle physics, both fixed target and collider , we never had to even think of the kinetic energy, it is useless in relativistic physics.  It is the energy in the center of mass that is important for comparing with models , and crucial to reach new frontiers, whether in fixed target or collider.

Comment: @anna  I would agree that talk about kinetic energies *instead* of energies is silly: that point appears to have been stuck in to confuse the student. Gain in an artificial quantity that means little...